# Тест на сообразительность

Tags: php

Возможно это мой внутренний баг, но этот код мне дался тяжело. С первого взгляда я оценил задачу в 2 мин. На деле, оказалось 10 - и мне стыдно!

Предлогаю засечь вам время и проверить за сколько вы напишете подобную задачу, которая выводит всего лишь логи на экран.

Подобный код: (я писал на php)

```
$console->log('program has been started')->('parsing data ... ',false)->log('parsed')->log('finished!').
```

Должен вывести следующее:

```
out says: program has been started\n
out says: parsing data ... parsed\n
out says: finished!\n
```

**Обновление**

```
$console->log('parsing ... ',false);
//код для парсига или тяжелое что то на 5 сек
sleep(5);
$console->log('done ');
$console->log('Finished ');
```

В итоге получится

> out says: parsing ... 
> done finished

Раз легко, то почему бы не написать?

Comment: где сама задача то ? вот я на js написал за секунды

     console.log('out says: program has been started');
     console.log('out says: parsing data ... parsed');
     console.log('out says: finished!');

больше всего времени заняло копипаста фраз.

на php это объект который в методе log выводит текст и  возвращает $this (видимо $console это его экземпляр) (че там - если второй параметр  false то не вставлять \n ? ) короче фигня а не задача.

Comment: банальная же задачка, я не понял, в чем загвоздка?

![Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/8pKaSbG.jpg?1)

Comment: Зачем решать очень легкую задачку?

Comment: а все же решение?

Comment: Вы про флаг установить для следующего вызова log ? ну я же сказал - формулировка никакая.

вот если бы вы поставили задачу чтобы 

    $console->log('Hello')->log('world');

вывел 

    LOG: Hello world;

а 

    $console->log('Hello');
    $console->log('world');

вывел

    LOG: Hello
    LOG: World

то это было бы хоть чуточку интереснее.

Comment: да в чем проблема-то

http://ideone.com/IBJW0g

минуты три, из которых полторы на тупой дебаг - не указал один раз log, неправильно назвал переменную

upd хорошо, неправильно прочитал условие, пять минут с учетом переделки

@eicto

> вот если бы вы поставили задачу чтобы

а это вообще реально без класса-обертки (возвращает не $this, а ChainWrapper($this)) или предварительного сетапа цепочки в самом классе?

Comment: ну да, два класса надо например, и возвращать экземпляр второго всегда. По крайней мере хоть чуть чуть подумать надо, понимая условие, а не как в исходной - главное условие вычитать :)

Comment: @Сергей Сергеевич

> $console->log('parsing ... ',false);
> //код для парсига или тяжелое что то на 5 сек
> sleep(5);
> $console->log('done ');
> $console->log('Finished ');

Конкретно такую задачку обычно бьют на `write()` и `writeLn()`, если это консольный вывод, всякие out says добавляются через обработку уже готового вывода (хотя никто не запретит вам сделать метод `beginLine()`), в лог же обычно сообщения пишутся сразу целиком (и там либо сразу пишется в файл с добавлением префикса, либо складируется в массив, которому потом в цикле делается любое форматирование).

Answer (score 5):

В общем как я уже говорил, ваша задача скучная, поэтому я её улучшил, в целом решение улучшенной задачи заняло у меня больше 10 мин, из-за пробела насчет деструктора, итак:

```
<?php

class Console
{
    public $lastLineClosed = true;
    public function __construct($closeLine=true) {
        $this->lastLineClosed = $closeLine;

    }
    public function  __destruct() {
        if (!$this->lastLineClosed) {
            echo PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) { //немного больше магии
        call_user_func_array($name,$arguments);
        return $this;
    }

    public function log($text)
    {
        if ($this->lastLineClosed) {
            echo 'out says: ';
            $text=ucfirst ($text);
        } else {
            $text=" ".$text;
        }
        echo $text;
        if ($this->lastLineClosed) {
            return new Console(false);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}

echo "---------\n";
$console = new Console;
$console ->log('Hello');
$console ->log('world');

$console ->log('Hello')->log('world');
$console ->log('Hello')->log('world')->magic_run(" magic! ")->log(2);
echo "---------\n";

function magic_run($arg) {
    sleep(3); //это мог бы быть ваш парсер :)
    echo " -==$arg==-";

}
```

http://ideone.com/z5osq3